# Issue while executing query to Cursor in rawQuery()

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, sqliteopenhelper

Unable to retrive data from external database data.db, it has already value stored in it. It throws error for table does not exist as there is already table with the data filled in database.

I have given READ and WRITE persmission in manifest.

DataBaseHelper.java

```
 public class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

@SuppressLint("SdCardPath")
private static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/com.example.databaseDemo/";

private static String DB_NAME = "data.db";

private SQLiteDatabase myDataBase;

private final Context myContext;
Cursor cursor;


public DataBaseHelper(Context context) {

    super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
    this.myContext = context;
}


public void createDataBase() throws IOException {

    boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();

    if (dbExist) {
        //do nothing - database already exist
    } else {


        this.getReadableDatabase();

        try {

            copyDataBase();

        } catch (IOException e) {

            throw new Error("Error copying database");

        }
    }

}

private boolean checkDataBase() {

    SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;

    try {
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

    } catch (SQLiteException e) {

        //database does't exist yet.

    }

    if (checkDB != null) {

        checkDB.close();

    }

    return checkDB != null ? true : false;
}


@Override
public synchronized SQLiteDatabase getReadableDatabase() {
    return super.getReadableDatabase();
}


private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {

    //Open your local db as the input stream
    InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

    // Path to the just created empty db
    String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

    //Open the empty db as the output stream
    OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

    //transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }

    //Close the streams
    myOutput.flush();
    myOutput.close();
    myInput.close();

}

public void openDataBase() throws SQLException {

    //Open the database
    String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
    myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY | SQLiteDatabase.NO_LOCALIZED_COLLATORS);

}

@Override
public synchronized void close() {

    if (myDataBase != null)
        myDataBase.close();

    super.close();

}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

}
public List<Album> getDataFromDB() {
    List<Album> modelList = new ArrayList<Album>();
    int i = 1;
    String query = "select * from Calls where call_key = " + i;

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            Album model = new Album();
            model.setName(cursor.getString(2));
            model.setNumOfSongs(cursor.getString(3));

            modelList.add(model);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    Log.d("student data", modelList.toString());
    return modelList;
  }
}
```

My Logcat:

```
   01-19 15:05:09.903 E/SQLiteLog: (1) no such table: Calls
   01-19 15:05:09.911 D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
   01-19 15:05:09.911 W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4191c2a0)
   01-19 15:05:09.919 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.databaseDemo.databasedemo/com.example.databaseDemo.databasedemo.MainActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: Calls (code 1): , while compiling: select * from Calls where call_key = 1
                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2097)
                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2122)
                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:140)
                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1228)
                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4895)
                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                                     at
```

**Note: I have confirmed many time that the table name mentioned in the query do exists. The same query returns data when tested in DB browser for SQLite.**

My Implementation in MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


RecyclerView recyclerView;
private MainAdapter adapter;
private List<Album> albumList;
DataBaseHelper helper;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);

    albumList = new ArrayList<>();


    LinearLayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());

    helper = new DataBaseHelper(this);
    albumList = helper.getDataFromDB();
    adapter = new MainAdapter(this, albumList);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    finish();
}
}
```

Comment: Where are you calling `createDataBase()` method?

Comment: where you create table in `@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

}
` first add table in this and than get.

Comment: @HemantParmar onCreate method is overrided in DataBaseHelper class.

Comment: @FirozMemon can you please mention me in code if I am missing any method calling in code?

Comment: @RakshitSorathiya yes its override but where you implement this? where you create table "Calls"?

Comment: @HemantParmar can you please tell me where I need to implement this ?

Comment: @RakshitSorathiya i post the ans please check.

Comment: `no such table: Calls` says it all.

Answer (score 0):

You getting data from table "Calls" but didn't create table, your `nCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)` implementation should be like this, change the field according to you want.

```
 @Override  
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {  
        String CREATE_CALLS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + "Calls "+ "("  
                + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_NAME + " TEXT,"  
                + KEY_PH_NO + " TEXT" + ")";  
        db.execSQL(CREATE_CALLS_TABLE );  
    }
```

Comment: The "Calls" table already exists with many records in externally used database data.db.

Comment: @RakshitSorathiya ok so you have to call those method in `onCreate()`.

Comment: It is not working. The error FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                     java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.databasedemo/com.example..databasedemo.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException